# Variance of Linear Combination in BSTS

Tags: probability, proof-verification, time-series

I'm studying Bayesian Structural Time Series package from Steven Scott (You can find it here [BSTS](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxzdGV2ZXRoZWJheWVzaWFufGd4OjI2ZGEwMTk4M2VmOWRkOTE)).

I was looking at a simple derivation for an AR(1) model:

[image: Variance of an AR(1)]

**My question is simple: is there a mistake in the notes when specifying $Var(Y_t)$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the slides you refer to includes a mistake. We can check this by calculating the variance of the $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ model. So let $Y_t = \phi Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ where $\lvert \phi\rvert < 1$ and $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ is an iid white noise process. Then

$$
\renewcommand{\var}{\operatorname{Var}}
\var(Y_t)
=
\var(\phi Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t)
=
\phi^2\var(Y_{t-1}) + \var(\varepsilon_t).
$$

As an $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ process with $\lvert\phi\rvert< 1$ is stationary, we have $\var (Y_t) = \var(Y_{t-1})$. Then
$$
\var(Y_t)  = \phi^2\var(Y_t) + \var(\varepsilon_t) \quad \iff \quad \var(Y_t) = \frac{\var(\varepsilon_t)}{1-\phi^2}
$$
by rearranging.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question after your comment

Comment: I commend you for noticing the possible mistake; critical reading like that will get you far!